# Draw Rectangle as Progressbar in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, progress-bar

I have a JFrame with a BorderLayout(). In the SOUTH Layout Constraint I want to put a progressbar. Not a dynamic one but one that gets set with a value (0-100) from time to time.
I thinking of a JPanel in which I draw a Rectangle with appropriate Width. 
How can I draw a rectangle inside a JPanel?

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 790, 539);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(0,0));
        frame.setResizable(false);

        JPanel panelSouth = new JPanel();

        frame.getContentPane().add(panelSouth, BorderLayout.WEST);
```

What I was thinking, maybe I could just resize the JPanel `panelSouth`. But in the Borderlayout it always stretches out to filll the whole SOUTH.

Comment: `How can I draw a rectangle inside a JPanel?` for example by folowing official Oracle tutorial `2D Graphics` or `Performing Custom Painting` or `How to Decorate Components with the JLayer Class` for Java7

Comment: `In the SOUTH Layout Constraint I want to put a progressbar. Not a dynamic one but one that gets set with a value (0-100) from time to time.` hmmm custom painting by default never returns any size, you have to set this preferredsize programatically, sure nothing cleaver only shorts into dark without your `SSCCE`

Comment: “Not a dynamic one but one that gets set with a value (0-100) from time to time.” I don’t get the meaning of this sentence. `JProgressBar` has a `setValue` method that you can call from time to time. So why don’t you use it? And what would be a “dynamic one”?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of starting from scratch, stick with `JProgressBar` to simplify your event coding. You can draw a rectangle in your implementation of the `paint()` method in a `BasicProgressBarUI`, as shown here with an ellipse drawn using `fillOval()` in `paintIndeterminate()`.

[image]